# "bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode" warning when listing directory on my FTP server

Tags: c, ftp

I am creating an FTP server as a school project, most of the commands are working and I almost nailed `PORT` (active mode for data transfer).

Launching my server using ftp like such:

```
ftp localhost 4242 // where 4242 is the port on which my server is listening
```

And using the command `ls` after logging in, I receive a working `ls` output followed by this message:

> WARNING! 8 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode
>   File may not have transferred correctly.

Please note that when using `ls` in `ftp`, it switches automatically to Active Mode before using the `LIST` command.

**What does this error signify?**

Full output:

```
200 Active Mode Enabled.
150 Directory listing.
total 56
drwxrwxr-x  4 kade_c kade_c  4096 mai   12 15:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 kade_c kade_c  4096 mai   12 14:58 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 kade_c kade_c  4096 mai   12 15:17 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 kade_c kade_c  1726 mai   11 10:35 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 kade_c kade_c   161 mai   11 11:43 README.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 kade_c kade_c 29368 mai   12 15:24 server
drwxrwxr-x  4 kade_c kade_c  4096 mai    2 18:40 server_src
WARNING! 8 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode
File may not have transferred correctly.
226 LIST complete.
```

And finally, here is the part of the code that creates, and connects to the socket and does the `ls -la`:

```
server_write(client, "150 Directory listing.\r\n");
if (connect_data(client) == -1) // Creates socket and connects to it
  {
    server_write(client, "520 Impossible to reach client.\r\n");
    return;
  }
ofd = xdup(1);
xdup2(client->data.socket, 1);
system("ls -la");
xdup2(ofd, 1);
server_write(client, "226 LIST complete.\r\n");
close_data(client, -1);
```

Comment: There is something very wring here. There is no "file" for a directory listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you send LF's to the client, and the client (rightly) expects CRLF's and warns about those missing CR's.

According to FTP specification, [RFC 959, section 3.4. Transmission modes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959#page-19), in the ASCII mode, you need to use CRLF exclusively:

> For the purpose of standardized transfer, the **sending host will
> translate its internal end of line or end of record denotation
> into the representation prescribed by the transfer mode** and file
> structure, and the receiving host will perform the inverse
> translation to its internal denotation.  ... **End-of-line in an ASCII  file with no
> record structure should be indicated by `<CRLF>`**

Answer (score 5):

This issue is because you are downloading files in ASCII mode. Switching to binary mode will make the warning disappear.

Once you login to the FTP server, type `binary` and then start downloading.

```
ftp> binary
200 Type set to I.
```

You only have to run this command once per FTP session.

Comment: The OP is implementing an FTP client in C (after all this is a programming Q&A site), not using a command-line `ftp` client (what would be off-topic question here).

Comment: Not only only that but binary mode can be problematic for code pages. Question is about the ls not the transfer of the file. ls is ALWAYS ASCII.